# Unit test for Highcharts tooltip in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, highcharts

I am using [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) in Angular 7+.

Suppose in some component, my chart type is '**area**' and my **tooltip** code is as follows:

```js
tooltip:{
    shared : true,
    outside : true,
    useHTML : true,
    formatter(){
        let str = `<table>`;
        this.points.forEach((point)=>{
            str = str.concat(
                `<tr>
                    <td style="color: ${point.series.color};font-size: 0.9em"></td>
                </tr>
                `
                );

            str = str.concat('</table>');
            return str;
        })
    }
}
```

Now while unit testing this component, the code coverage was not 100% and in the index.html file it showed the tooltip part is not covered. How to check for the same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want to unit test high charts? Unit tests should cover your business logic implementation. You should not be concerned about testing libraries. They do that already (if they are a good library). 100% coverage is a dated misconception. It’s more important to have a good meaningful coverage that supports your use cases than having 100% for the sake of it. What happens when the main goal is chasing those numbers is that you end up spending more time trying to overcome something that you shouldn’t even be testing in the first place than investing time in doing the meaningful tests.

Tests should test the code you produce (or your team) and should cover requirements and use cases. They should test behaviour and not implementation. Even less 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. May i know how to check for correct data in tooltip in general? Means whether the value being rendered is expected or not.

Comment: Can you also suggest something for this too:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168588/unit-testing-gridsizechanged-of-ag-grid-in-angular-7

Comment: Those kinds of features you can test by using an acceptance tests (or e2e tests tool). For instance protractor or cypress. With those tools you set expectations about what you should be seeing in the screen like if you were a user. Have a look.

Comment: May i ask which one are you talking about? tooltip one or gridSizeChanged one?

Comment: Can you  also help me with this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176688/checking-local-variable-while-unit-testing-on-a-component-in-angular-gives-error

Comment: Hello @Hugo Noro, can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725741/uncaught-typeerror-shown-in-karma-when-unit-testing-in-angular and also with this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719672/checking-for-correctly-calculated-combined-values-while-unit-testing-in-angular

Comment: Hello, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095430/callback-and-testing-highcharts

Answer (score 2):

In your test, you can programmatically show a tooltip by using `onMouseOver` method and check for example the generated string by: `chart.tooltip.label.text.textStr`:

```
chart.series[0].points[2].onMouseOver();
console.log(chart.tooltip.label.text.textStr);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4950/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#onMouseOver

Comment: Hello @ppotaczek, can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725741/uncaught-typeerror-shown-in-karma-when-unit-testing-in-angular and also with this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719672/checking-for-correctly-calculated-combined-values-while-unit-testing-in-angular

Comment: Hi @Rahul Chowdhury, Sorry, but I am not an angular specialist. I can help you only with Highcharts.

Comment: No problem. Thank you. Can you.. ask someone maybe in your connections if possible?

Comment: Hello @ppotaczek, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095430/callback-and-testing-highcharts                 Also please help me in improving the question if necessary, it my first writing a question with entire code on stackblitz :)

Comment: Hi @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI, I see that your problem has already been resolved. I follow all questions with `highcharts` tag, so in the future you only need to use the tag.

Comment: Not entirely actually, i am yet to know when to call chart callback and updateFlag should be called? and also when is the chart finally created so that i can write complete answer. Also i will surely take into account your tag part :)                                             i wrote the test cases based on the suggestion of @gsa.interactive , who knows he may also miss out on something?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I have forwarded the question to our Angular developer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be of great help to me. :)

Comment: Here's a demo of how the `updateFlag` works: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-uqe80?file=/src/app/app.component.ts It basically tells Angular that changes have been made in the options object and the chart should be redrawn (Angular doesn't notice nested changes in options). Notice that the update won't happen without this line: `chart.updateDemo = true;`.
`callbackFunction` is the same thing as the load event: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
It launches when the chart is fully rendered and ready run the initial animation.

Comment: Hello @Kamil , thank you for your answer. Can you post your answer here and maybe look into the question , I have tried to make it a bit more concise about what my problem is along with code example.           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140215/highcharts-instance-created-in-which-angular-life-cycle-hook

Comment: Hey @Kamil Kulig, thanks man. It did help a lot. Can you upvote my question also :). So that it reaches more number of people.