# Highcharts instance created in which Angular life cycle hook

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am currently using Angular 7+ with [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/).

I integrated Highcharts using the following [Official Github Link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular).

There is a `callbackFunction` in Highcharts which we can use to get the chart instance .
However, i am yet to figure out 2 things:

1. When does the **actual instance of chart** gets created along with the `options`, like in which **lifecycle hook** in Angular? Or is it independent of the lifecycle hooks.
2. I saw a developer's example in which he used the **`callbackFunction`** while inside the **`ngOnInit`** lifecycle hook and it worked ( i.e we got a chart instance from the callback ). However the same did not work for **`ngOnChanges`** hook.

   So my point was that, suppose there is an `@Input` property related to `graph data` which is to be rendered by the Highcharts.chart ( like say appending a new series ), then i would have to use ngOnChanges method in order to detect changes in input property and **ngOnChanges would be called before ngOnInit** as per [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/) . How would i get the chart instance then ? and how would i do an addSeries then ?
3. Why does **`addSeries`** work only on `button click` and not in ngOnInit ? Uncomment **line number 59** inside `hello.component.ts` to see it.

[Link to the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1alit3).

Please see `hello.component.ts` for any details.

Comment: You should share code you tried

Comment: Done. Do see and tell if anything more is required?

Comment: Do you want to send from appcomponent and auto change in hellocomponent ?

Comment: Yes, i would want the same phenomenon as happening when i do button click , with line number 59 uncommented. i.e adding more series.

Comment: hello.component.ts is holding the chart, right? If thats the case I would suggest the ngOnInit() function of that component will lead you access on its children components like the cart and its properties. This is why you get undefined. And the ngOnChanges() hook is called before the ngOnInit hook. Please read (especially the 2nd blue box: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#initializing-a-component-or-directive)

Comment: Hello @gsa.interactive , take a look at the code which i wrote in which i removed ngOnInit ,maybe it helped you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-itc97n)
Here you just need to update chartoptions
If you want update data

```
ngOnChanges(){
    console.log(this.newData); 
    this.chartOptions.series[0]=this.newData;      
  }
```

If you want add new series

```
ngOnChanges(){
    console.log('Inside ngOnchanges');
    this.chartOptions.series.push(this.newData)   
  }
```

1. Highchart is created after you set chartoptions of Highchart
2. You can define callback ngOnchange or ngOnInit.In both it works. But you missed that `your this.chartCreated.addSeries(this.newData)` is not working there because it is async function so outside of callback you may not define `chartCreated`. If you put this code in callback function you will see that it will add new series. Your first series created with  chartoptions.
3. It works with onclick because before click your callback has already defined your `chartCreated` That is why click works.

As a final you don't need to create extra variable ,you can use chartoptions to update or add new series.

Comment: thank you for your response. But could you also please briefly answer the 3 questions that i have asked? also is there no way to do it using addSeries ?

Comment: I updated answer with your questions @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can i say that chart callback and addSeries are both async from your conclusion?

Comment: callback is aync

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. I am posting a piece of code to support your explanation. Have a look. :)

Comment: Hello @pc_coder, can you help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394625/unit-testing-asynchronous-code-including-setinterval-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

As per explanation given by @pc_coder , i removed **`ngOnInit`**, and implemented **`addSeries`** inside **`ngOnChanges`** and it worked.

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() newData: any;
  title = 'AngularTest';
  chartCreated;


  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction;
  updateFlag: boolean = false;
  clicked:boolean = false;

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      type: 'line'
    }]
  };

  // ngOnInit(){
  //   console.log('Inside ngOnInit');
  //   this.chartCallback = (chart) => {
  //               this.chartCreated = chart;
  //               console.log('chart: ' + chart); // shows object
  //           }
  //  
  // }

  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log('Inside ngOnchanges');
    this.chartCallback = (chart) => {                  
                this.chartCreated = chart;
                console.log('chart: ' + chart);
                this.chartCreated.addSeries(this.newData); // This worked :)
            }

  }


  onClick(){
    if(this.clicked==false){
      this.chartCreated.series[0].data[0].update(4);
      this.clicked = true;
    //this.chartCreated.addSeries(this.newData); // works on uncommenting  
    }
    else{
      this.chartCreated.series[0].data[0].update(1);
      this.clicked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

It supports his point that : " **callback is async and does not depend on OnInit/OnChanges** " and also " **chart instance is created after the options for it is set** ".

Comment: And callback is fired after initial load completed. It means while you added inside callback. It means chart is ready to add series to it.

Comment: Hey @pc_coder, thanks man. It did help a lot. Can you upvote my question also :). So that it reaches more number of people.